# DVWA vulnerability list or guide?

Tags: web-application, dvwa

Is there a list of vulnerabilities for DVWA, I cannot seem to find a vulnerability list or guide.

By guide I mean an exhaustive list of vulnerabilities to work through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DVWA separates each vulnerability into its own page.  Each page is accessible on the menu to the left.  Each vulnerability is a textbook example of the flaw,  there should be nothing strange going on so any documentation on that vulnerability is useful.   If you don't understand the very basics of a flaw,  then I'm sure OWASP has a page on it.  You could also try and find an exploit for the specific flaw "in the wild" (like exploit-db.com).

Answer (score 1):

http://securitytube-tools.net/index.php?title=DVWA
 security tube has good stuff. go to the page above and they have a link to vids on dvwa